# what causing this Exception in this method? java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java

so im writing a function that is suppose to only return relevant dates (aka. Mondays):

```
private List<String> getRelevantDates(Vector<String> dates) {

        List<String> relevantDates = new ArrayList<>();

        for (var i = 0; i < dates.size(); i += 7) {

            for (var j = 0; j < i; j += 4) {

                var currentElement = dates.elementAt(i);
                var previousElement = dates.elementAt(i -= 7);

                if (currentElement.charAt(j) != previousElement.charAt(j)) {
                    i = dates.indexOf(currentElement);
                }

            }

            relevantDates.add(dates.elementAt(i));

        }

        return relevantDates;

    }
```

The paramater "dates" holds all dates in a certain interval e.g from 01.03.2020 to 05.03.2020 it would be [01.03.2020, 02.03.2020, 03.03.2020, 04.03.2020, 05.03.2020]. What exactly is causing this Exception? Is there a differnt way to do it?

Comment: "Is there a differnt way to do it?" Yes, use a proper class to represent your dates, e.g. `java.time.LocalDate`, that you can add 7 days to.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> var previousElement = dates.elementAt(i -= 7);
> ```

This shouldn't be an assignment. Make it simply `-`.

```
var previousElement = dates.elementAt(i - 7);
```

> What exactly is causing this Exception?

Due to the fact that `i` is decreased more than increased, the external loop becomes infinite, and the list `relevantDates` will end up to fill all the available memory.